# VS CODE - как включить подсветку или изменить цвет текста выделенного фрагмента?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Для VS CODE написано множество расширений, позволяющих настроить цветовое выделение кода, но я не нашёл такого, которое могло бы окрасить в нужный цвет произвольный участок кода, так, как если бы мы делали это в Word'е или документах Google.

В идеале было бы круто оттолкнуться от функции, которая запускается в VS CODE при выделении фрагмента и нажатии ctrl+F (поиск). Там подсвечиваются все вхождения в документе, но выделение каждый раз сбрасывается при новом поиске, а хотелось бы чтобы оно оставалось и к нему можно было добавлять новые фрагменты.

Такой функционал был бы удобен для отметки полностью оформленного кода, который хотелось бы скрыть затенением, а не сворачиванием.

Может быть есть такое расширение? Или команда? Или хоткей уже встроенный?

Comment: И таких много.. К примеру, первое же в поиске - [Text Marker (Highlighter)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryu1kn.text-marker) от Ryuichi Inagaki

Comment: от Блииин, и правда ))) Просто нужно было вместо "хайлайтера" написать "текст маркер".. И это расширение, пожалуй, самое подходящее!